# Error while trying to connect to sql server database from C#.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is the code

```
public string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myconnection"];

public int get_details(string team1_name, string team2_name)
{
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string sql = "insert into Table(team1_name,team2_name) values(@team1_name,@team2_name)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team1_name", team1_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team2_name", team2_name);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
}
```

Whenever I run this code, the error says

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in dblayer.dll
>
> Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger to see what `connectionString` is set to?

Comment: have you check the connection string ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**  You need touse following statement to initilialise the connectionstring properly.

```
public string connectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
         [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myconnection"]].ConnectionString;
```

**Solution 2:**

`Table` is keyword hence you need to enclose it within the square brackets `[]`.

Replace This:

```
string sql = "insert into Table(team1_name,team2_name) 
                                                values(@team1_name,@team2_name)";
```

With :

```
string sql = "insert into [Table](team1_name,team2_name) 
                                                values(@team1_name,@team2_name)";
```

Comment: I tried both solution 1 and 2, this shows the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in dblayer.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @user3769584: are you getting exception at `connectionstring` could you debug and see is really connectionstring` getting initialised.

Comment: @user3769584: could you please share your config file, where your `connectionstring` hasbeen initialised.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myconnection" value="data source=ritesh-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cricscore;Integrated Security=true;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: @user3769584: is it winform application or webapplication?

Comment: try this: `string connectionString =System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myconnection"];`

Comment: it is a winform application

Comment: the error says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in dblayer.dll

Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Connection String:

```
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="conName" connectionString="Server=ServerName;initial catalog=DBName;User ID=sa;Password=sa123;"/> // SQL server Authentication
 </connectionStrings>
<configuration>

 public string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString;


    public int get_details(string team1_name, string team2_name)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "insert into Table(team1_name,team2_name) values(@team1_name,@team2_name)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team1_name", team1_name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team2_name", team2_name);
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in dblayer.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @user3769584 can you please post your connectionstring from web.config ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myconnection" value="data source=ritesh-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cricscore;Integrated Security=true;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: "Null reference exception was unhandled" error occurs

Comment: The config file doesn't recognize the keyword "name" and "connectionString"

Comment: @Roshan, if it is winform application please read this http://nareshkamuni.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-insert-edit-update-and-delete.html